# having category headings for list dictionaries in python/django

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have the following list dictionary in django:

```
items = [{'category':'apple','item':'granny smith'},
 {'category':'apple','item':'cox'},
 {'category':'apple','item':'pixie'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'premier'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'queen'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'westin'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'breakfast'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'lady grey'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'builders'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'colombia'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'kenya'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'brazil'}]
```

how do I get it to display in the template like:

```
apple:
    granny smith
    cox
    pixie
orange:
    premier
    queen
    ...
```

Should I be doing this (the logic I mean) in the view or in the template? And also what happen if I only want to show the first five of the list? I need a solution that will not give me empty categories

**EDIT**

I must admit that this is an over simplification of my problem and the actual list I dealing with is already being sorted by `datetime` like so:

```
items.sort(key=lambda item:item['created'], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group all the items by category:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = [{'category':'apple','item':'granny smith'},
 {'category':'apple','item':'cox'},
 {'category':'apple','item':'pixie'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'premier'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'queen'},
 {'category':'orange','item':'westin'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'breakfast'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'lady grey'},
 {'category':'tea','item':'builders'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'colombia'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'kenya'},
 {'category':'coffee','item':'brazil'}]

result = defaultdict(list)
for item in items:
    result[item['category']].append(item['item'])
```

And in the template:

```
{% for key, values in result.items() %}
    <span>{{key}}</span>
    <ul>
    {% for item in values %}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your going to have to explain whats going on here. I'm not to sure I understand

Comment: @Sevenearths `result` is a dictionary like: `{'orange':['premier', 'queen', 'westin'], 'tea':['breakfast', 'lady grey', 'builders'], ...}`. Thus, iterating over the values for each key you have all the items corresponding to each category.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can jig this for my needs now I understand it :)